# Node http server ends before await operations are finished

Tags: node.js

I have an http server running in nodeJS. What needs to happen is the following:

- A user posts a string to the server
- a folder is created with a name equal to the posted string
- copies a file from the root to the new folder
- opens the file and replaces placeholders
- saves the file again
- server needs to wait 5 seconds
- then sends the response back to the client

So far, everything works... accept, the server sends the respons practically immediately, instead of waiting the 5 seconds.
In the frontend, the call gets "canceled".

When I remove all the logic regarding folder creation and file copy and just keep the time out for 5 seconds.... It works fine. So, am I doing something wrong with the file operations?

```html
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
var fs = require("fs");
const { readFile, writeFile, promises: fsPromises } = require("fs");

const port = 8080;

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    const headers = {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": `${req.headers.origin}`,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, POST, GET",
      "Access-Control-Max-Age": 2592000,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.writeHead(204, headers);
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (["GET", "POST"].indexOf(req.method) > -1) {
      let data = "";
      req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      req.on("end", async () => {
        const message = JSON.parse(data);
        const msg = message.msg;
        const outputDir = __dirname + "/" + msg.replace(/\s/g, "");
        await fsPromises.mkdir(outputDir);
        await fsPromises.copyFile(
          __dirname + "/update-text.jsx",
          outputDir + "/update-text.jsx"
        );
        const contents = await fsPromises.readFile(
          outputDir + "/update-text.jsx",
          "utf-8"
        );
        const replaced = contents.replace(
          /{{MESSAGE}}/gi,
          msg.replace(/\s/g, "")
        );
        await fsPromises.writeFile(outputDir + "/update-text.jsx", replaced);
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
        res.writeHead(200, headers);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ ready: true }));
      });
      return;
    }

    res.writeHead(405, headers);
    res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);
  })
  .listen(port);
console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. My test shows it's working now. Review commented out section of the code.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const { readFile, writeFile, promises: fsPromises } = require('fs');


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
};

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    const headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': req.headers.origin,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.writeHead(204, headers);
      return res.end();
    }

    if (['GET', 'POST'].indexOf(req.method) > -1) {
      let data = '';

      req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      req.on('end', async () => {
        const message = JSON.parse(data);
        const { msg } = message;
        const outputDir =  `/${msg.replace(/\s/g, "")}`;
        await fsPromises.mkdir(outputDir);
        await fsPromises.copyFile(
          `update-text.jsx`,
          `${outputDir}/update-text.jsx`
        );
        const contents = await fsPromises.readFile(
          `${outputDir}/update-text.jsx`,
          'utf-8'
        );
        const replaced = contents.replace(
          /{{MESSAGE}}/gi,
          msg.replace(/\s/g, '')
        );
        await fsPromises.writeFile(`${outputDir}/update-text.jsx`, replaced);
        console.log('Sleeping for 5 seconds…');
        await sleep(5000);
        console.log('Sleep Over. Sending Response.');
        res.writeHead(200, headers);
        return res.end(JSON.stringify({ ready: true }));
      });
    }

    // Issue is here. This code is outside of the above async block and
    // is called before the async returns.
    // res.writeHead(405, headers);
    // res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);
  })
  .listen(PORT);

console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
```

Output:

```
Listening at http://localhost:8080

Sleeping for 5 seconds…

Sleep Over. Sending Response.
```

Also, you may want to check the front end code to verify you need to wait five seconds. I think the front end was receiving an HTTP 405 error. The sleep is likely not necessary.

I would like to state that it's generally best not to allow write access to the filesystem. If you still choose to do so, you will want to validate and sanitize the request.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I removed the line for the timeout and replaced it with your code sample, but no luck. The timeout works, but the response is already send...

Comment: @MarioVde please check out my updated answer. The last res functions are outside of the async function and are executed prior to the sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrew, that fixed it!
Also, I found another error in my VSCode plugin.
I have this live-server installed, that I can start from VS Code.
It has hot reloading and all that stuff,
BUT!
It also reloads the page when there is a directory created or files created, hence canceling the api-call.

Thanks a bunch!